# creating a sublist from a list in python

Tags: python

please help me, i want to write a function that takes a list as an argument and returns a new list of elements that appear more than once from the original list. I tried writing it this way but it doesn't give me the answer

```
def list(n):
    l = [ ]
    for s in n:
        if n.count(s) > 1:
            l.append(s)
        return l
    return None
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`filter()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) function to do that.
This is not the most fast for CPU but laconic and pythonic enough.

```
my_list = [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7]
print filter(lambda x: my_list.count(x) > 1, my_list)
```

[**DEMO #1**](http://codepad.org/bWjQESl0)

Also you can use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) as [6502](https://stackoverflow.com/users/320726/6502) mentioned:

```
my_list = [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7]
print [x for x in my_list if my_list.count(x) > 1]
```

[**DEMO #2**](http://codepad.org/kWxs145a)

Comment: Shouldn't be `set(my_list)` instead of `my_list` as last argument of `filter`?

Comment: No it shouldn't because `set()` will return you a collection of unique values.

Comment: I was talking only about last parameter, not both uses (thus returning duplicated values but only once). BTW: most uses of `filter`+`lambda` can be substituted by shorter and more pythonic list comprehensions: `[x for x in set(L) if L.count(x) > 1]`

Comment: @6502 About the last parameter and set - don't you think that the `set()` constructor will iterate through the list to create a set so we'll get one more hidden loop?

Comment: Yes, but done only once and in C. BTW how can be one more iteration over the list a problem given that there is one iteration for each element in `count`?

Comment: Though if we'll use `set(my_list)` in list comprehension or as second argument in `filter()` we'll get each repeated value only once. And @Ademola Sodiq want them as is.

Answer (score 2):

You're close.  You need to remove the `return` statement from the for loop.  As it is, you return unconditionally after the first element.

```
def list(n):
    l = []
    for s in n:
        if n.count(s) > 1:
           l.append(s)
    return l
```

Second, I highly recommend that you don't use `list` as the name of this function as then you shadow the builtin `list` function which is very useful.

Comment: Also using a lowercase `L` as variable name is not the best for readability.

Comment: @6502 -- That's a reasonable point as well.  Addressed in the [python style guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#names-to-avoid) in fact ...

Answer (score 1):

```
def list_duplicates(seq):
  seen = set()
  seen_add = seen.add
  #adds all elements it doesn't know yet to seen and all other to seen_twice
  seen_twice = set( x for x in seq if x in seen or seen_add(x) )
  # turn the set into a list (as requested)
  return list( seen_twice )

 a = [1,2,3,2,1,5,6,5,5,5]
 list_duplicates(a)
```

This will print

```
[1,2,5]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think solution of `Eugene Naydenov` is good, but I some enhance it:

```
In [1]: my_list = [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7];
In [2]: set_list = lambda(lst) : list(set(i for i in filter(lambda x: my_list.count(x) > 1, lst))) #set_list is function
In [3]: set_list(my_list)
Out[3]: [2, 4, 5]
```